# Combining a navigationcontroller and a root view controller with pages

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a problem that has been solved on iOS6, but still appears if I use the iOS 5.1 simulator.

I have a default page based application. I added a "Main menu" view controller, that has three buttons that activate the root view controller containing the pages via a push segue, all defined in the storyboard.

I then added a navigation controller and made it the initial view controller.

If I pas the menu via a button and flip a few pages I can click the back button and it goes back to the menu. Good.

But I don't want the nav bar, so I hide it, and on the root view controller that contains the page view controllers I add a button which performs this action:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This button works perfect on iOS6, I can flip a few pages, press the button and I'm back in the menu.

With the iOS 5.1 simulator however (and on my 5.1 iPad), a page flip occurs! It's a page filp until I'm on the last page and then I go back to the menu.

I searched for over two hours now but could not find a solution, I hope someone can help me with this?

Note: setting animated to NO does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer to my question, this is my first iOS project which explains why I did not find it any sooner myself.

In the default page based application there are two lines in the viewDidLoad method:

```
// Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily
self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
```

First, it's not really adding but assigning that happens here, second, when I put the second line in comment, everything works as expected.

So I'm glad it solves my problem, however it raises some questions:

1. The gestures are started as easy as they were, so why was this line needed in the first place, what does it supposedly fix?
2. Why does it work in iOS6? It should have had the same problem, no?
3. Is it correct that it is an assignment and not an addition?

Any answers to these three are still appreciated.

Alex